# React Redux Actions Typesafety

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have a simple Counter Example through which i will explain my confusion .

Counter.Types

```
export interface DecrementAction {
  type: typeof Types.DECREMENT;
  decrementBy: number
}
```

Types

```
export const Types = {
  DECREMENT :Symbol("DECREMENT")
}
```

Counter.Action

```
export const decrementAction = (decrementBy: number): DecrementAction => ({
  type: Types.DECREMENT,
  decrementBy: decrementBy
});

export type CounterActionTypes = DecrementAction;
```

Counter.Reducer

```
const counter = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action : CounterActionTypes) => {

  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.DECREMENT:
      return {
        count: state.count - action.decrementBy // this dosen't work ts complains decrementBy present in action

      };
    default:
      return state;
  }

};
```

If i change the line in case to this         `count: state.count - (action as DecrementAction).question` Typescript stops complaining.

I have come from ngrx world where we can straight away add `payload.<ref>`. What am i missing here ? How can we not add `<action as ..>` and directly reference the actions variables .

Comment: Please add definition of `Types` and `CounterActionTypes`. This is currently not reproducable.

Comment: @emlai i updated it they were minor files so i thought i will not be imp, thanks for helping out

Comment: The provided code still doesn't reproduce the problem. Anyway, check my answer, it might help.

Comment: @emlai i tried the answer still the same bug i get `property number dosent exist on type CounterActions.Property number dosent exist in type increment Action`

Comment: It works fine in the typescript playground. I can't reproduce your problem if you don't provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I don't think TypeScript doesn't support symbols as union discriminators. You can just use strings though:

```
export const Types = {
  DECREMENT: "DECREMENT",
  INCREMENT: "INCREMENT"
} as const

export interface DecrementAction {
  type: typeof Types.DECREMENT;
  decrementBy: number
}

export interface IncrementAction {
  type: typeof Types.INCREMENT;
  incrementBy: number
}

export const decrementAction = (decrementBy: number): DecrementAction => ({
  type: Types.DECREMENT,
  decrementBy: decrementBy
});

export type CounterActionTypes = DecrementAction | IncrementAction;

const INITIAL_STATE = { count: 0 };

const counter = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action: CounterActionTypes) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.DECREMENT:
      return {
        count: state.count - action.decrementBy
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wCoE8zFXAXjgG8AoOOAEQFEBhAJWoFlqA5DALjgCIaHm2GbgBpycAJKt+Ldl26Tpg7qQC+cAIb4kaGKVKhIsOAEtkMYFABm6hMCrAEUYAFtgZgIIIYxlCTEwcYC4A3AhLOGxcVAA6PkYZDABuMQATBydXMwAhLC5kAFdnACMLVT0DaHhTcysbO3FkRxc3GE9vXzIKEKC4brCIwJiFeMFkilMmzJgcvMKSqDL9cErEFHQ4NMmWtp9kQjgACk2Mlpm4AuKLAEouSnTmjy9dwgA+Q87ewK5IvFi6EfYogoxwe01yG3uUxyqiuySWhng3TgtAg+TMFh2KB++CIdy2j3aewAPhJGicCbs4dp1pJxBhxO4ADIAfQAyhh3BhqPtiKs0TAuAAGOAqKlreBIfkWfYHdDqcz7Wn0plsjlc4QaJ4oLgoqVQTHIbFXV5+CioADuxhgCAAFocbITot1jR8KAhNHZsX9FLIxBQKE4YPkoHtXf63aizFw5eZopKzHAALSax0gqFYP3+0WZtLWfIAGwFmYDwCDIbgMeAYxFqmSQA)

Also `Types` could be an enum:

```
export enum Types {
  DECREMENT = "DECREMENT",
  INCREMENT = "INCREMENT"
}
```

Then you don't need the `typeof` in `type: typeof Types.DECREMENT;`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwCoE8zAM5wDeAUHHACICiAwgEqUCylAchnALxwBEVdjLGLgBpScAJLM+TVh24SpArsQC+xYqEiw4AS0QxgUAGYBDAMbAKwU1GCokMAIKmY2iIiKiYOYAC5M3vAA6XnppDABuUQATKxs7PQAhLD8UVAAjAxU1DWh4XX0jMwsxRGtbeycXNw8yL1w-bFwg+VCBSLJdMviYJJS0DKgs9XBcuFM3PHgYrornV3dOAAppuPteuFSBgEo-cljyvUr5jgA+OEWSWu8GgOCaVtYRMhWDnuS4F+6klS3I4c14HULNQIMg9AYjm5GvhZHsZoc5tUAD7iUqrBFVRB-caISbiZhiDBiBwAGQA+gBlDAODCUWSEMagvR+AAMcGU2Im8HGYIKskWk2M+lkEkJxPJVJplCEcDMmL8IN5EMRiGheC2pxqcDwAHdtDBTAALc5y+aBIEay5kMbGPAWNV3BSsHyia1wGwwZBQdxWt1kHnM7UwIXAQIB+AAWllKsCnzWWFd1o5iZiJmQABsYC6-e7gJ7vUGQ+12SpIkA)